csvsql is giving ArgumentError when query argument is present
Below command runs fine
> echo '{"a":{"b":"c"},"d":"e"}' | in2csv -f ndjson | csvsql
CREATE TABLE stdin (
    "a/b" VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    d VARCHAR NOT NULL
);

But whenever I use --query argument I get below error
> echo '{"a":{"b":"c"},"d":"e"}' | in2csv -f ndjson | csvsql --query 'SELECT "a/b" FROM stdin'
ArgumentError: expected schema argument to be a string, got \<class 'sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection'\>.

I installed via conda
conda install conda-forge::csvkit

csvsql --version
csvsql 1.5.0


Did you figure it out?
